# Which JSF-tag to use to get the path of an Input Directory on the client side?

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

Is there an input directory for JSF, or library like Omnifaces or Primefaces? I don't need `<h:inputFile>` as the file actually no need to be uploaded, I would like to provide a field for user to input the path of a file for example:

```
C:\Folder One\myFile.txt
```

and ManagedBean will interpret the path, for example, read the content of the file. I don't want user to enter the file path manually in input text. And I don't have the client/server issue as the user will select the file on the machine which my JSF application is deployed.

If such component is not available, is there any workaround? like maybe I can provide a `<h:inputFile>` and get path from it?

Comment: Try to see if you can in plain html/javascript (since that is what actually runs on the client)

Comment: I think you can't